# Maven: Different library versions in one JVM

Tags: java, maven

I have a project whose dependency tree is huge i.e. it packs in modules from several teams.

Now there are some commonly used dependencies which are common across several modules.

A simplified example can be:

```
TopModule.jar
  ChildModule.jar
    CommonModule-v1.jar
  CommonModule-v2.jar
```

When I build my project, I specify the latest version of common dependencies, but its very hard to ask the same from every other team.

So, frequently, the TopModule is built using different versions of CommonModule (v1 and v2 in the above example).

My question is:

If the final jar file contains both CommonModule-v1.jar and CommonModule-v2.jar, how does it affect the runtime?

Can the runtime erroneously load versions v2 where v1 is required and vice versa?

Comment: What do you mean by "final jar file contains both `CommonModule-v1.jar` and `CommonModule-v2.jar`"? You usually don't package JARs inside other JARs. Your question doesn't really make much sense the way Java apps are commonly deployed. (Which is with a flat list of all transitive dependencies somewhere on the classpath.)

Comment: Maven will use the newest version, you could try dependency:analyze-duplicate.

Comment: @millimoose, welcome to maven

Comment: @user2250246 I know Maven well enough and what you describe is not how Maven works. For one `mvn package` will only JAR up the given module's class files, it doesn't do anything with the dependencies after the compilation. If you're making a WAR, then it will put the dependencies into `WEB-INF/lib/`, but in that case it will pick one of the versions, not both. (Unless the different versions have a different `groupId`+`artifactId`, which isn't really something Maven can handle automatically.) So how about instead of being glib you describe what's actually going on?

Comment: **tl;dr**: Maven does not, by default, put `jar`s inside other `jar`s. If yours does, post the relevant configuration.

Comment: millimoose, I got my answer from the below responses. So I guess it was glib enough.

Answer (score 4):

Maven will only use one version of each artifact in the end -- it doesn't do any fancy classloader isolation tricks. You can see which version it'll use with `mvn dependency:resolve`.

If you need to use specific versions within dependencies, you can use the [shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). It'll do renaming trickery so that dependencies get their own versions of libraries.

Answer (score 1):

To fight with this problem globally use this [DependencyConvergence Rule](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html)

> This rule requires that dependency version numbers converge. If a
>   project has two dependencies, A and B, both depending on the same
>   artifact, C, this rule will fail the build if A depends on a different
>   version of C then the version of C depended on by B.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce</id>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <DependencyConvergence/>
          </rules>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

After this all teams work together with consistent versions of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If your pom.xml is only an aggregator of already packaged modules then this apply. If it is not the case and your project actually compile and packages all of those modules as a submodules then maven will choose one. If it compiles every project on its own then it will be packaged using that dependency. But if all of them end up in the same class loader then it won't work fine.

At runtime it can cause errors, think of `method not found` and the like. Your byte code classes were compiled and linked with the correct dependencies but since the class loader finds two candidates it just load one at runtime.

What you can do is set a parent pom defining a `<dependencyManagement>` and then ask all teams to use it as a parent and don't declare `<version>` but inherit it from the parent pom.xml.

References http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management

Comment: Maven will automatically only pick *one* version of a JAR when it's found twice in a build. `<dependencyManagement>` is however the way to decide which version that is.

Comment: He says that package modules together. Those modules might be already packaged. But it is just a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the way the modules are named in maven. Usually, maven tries to resolve the conflicting libs and takes the highest version into the tree. But if the libraries are different artifacts in terms of artifactId, then maven will not see that they are from the same breed and thus will not resolve the ambiguity.

Usually you resolve this by a common parent.pom, where you define the versions of commonly used libraries throughout the project. If you have no control over the other projects (not part of your build, only dependencies), you may be lucky to have your final project working fine. If the library breaks compatibility in the newer version, you will not be able to use it.

So, does your final project contain both versions of the library or not, did you check it? The dependency tree may show both versions, but if maven will use only the latest version of a dependency in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Classloader will load the first JAR which appears on your classpath. In more details - it will search for the first class on your class path, so in each case all these searches would fall into i.e. `CommonModule-v2.jar`. So the answer is yes - it can erroneously load versions v2 where v1 if it appears earlier on your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

On top of what @yshavit said, ideally you'd exclude the earlier version of the `CommonModule` so that only v2 is in the classpath.  This is only possible if the `CommonModule` v2 api is backwards compatible with `CommonModule` v1.

Here's an example of how you exclude:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ChildModuleGroupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>ChildModuleArtifactid</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>CommonModuleGroupId</groupId>
                <artifactId>CommonModuleArtifactId</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

You'd put that in the TopModule pom.xml.